# Maven compile with lombok project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, plugins

I have been sucesfully compiling and deploying code, until I have cleared local repository, and ever since than I am not able to compile code using maven.
It is spring boot project.
When I run it in Eclipse as Spring Boot App it runs smoothly, but when I try to compile it with **mvn clean package** i got error. It looks like as it has no annotation processor for lombok. I have tried all solutions proposed so far on stackowerflow, but still nothing.

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< com.kota:CopyCenter >-------------------------
[INFO] Building CopyCenter 1.0.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ CopyCenter ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\kotar\git\CopyCenter\CopyCenter\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ CopyCenter ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] Copying 18 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ CopyCenter ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 215 source files to C:\Users\kotar\git\CopyCenter\CopyCenter\target\classes
[INFO] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/model/interni/Cenovnik.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[INFO] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/model/interni/Cenovnik.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/AdresaServices.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/AdresaServices.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/model/Radnja.java:[47,90] an enum annotation value must be an enum constant
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/model/Korisnik.java:[40,8] com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik is not abstract and does not override abstract method getPassword() in org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/model/Adresa.java:[43,37] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getGrad()
  location: variable grad of type @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull(message="Grad mora biti unet") com.kota.cc.model.Grad
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/model/Adresa.java:[44,37] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getDrzava()
  location: variable grad of type @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull(message="Grad mora biti unet") com.kota.cc.model.Grad
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/model/Kopija.java:[36,8] com.kota.cc.model.Kopija is not abstract and does not override abstract method getCena() in com.kota.cc.model.interfaces.Buyable
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/model/Kopija.java:[114,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getName()
  location: variable zaStampu of type com.kota.cc.model.Upload
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/model/Kopija.java:[119,39] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getBrojStrana()
  location: variable upload of type com.kota.cc.model.Upload
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/model/Kopija.java:[125,46] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getBrojStrana()
  location: variable upload of type com.kota.cc.model.Upload
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/model/Kopija.java:[139,59] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getBrojStrana()
  location: variable upload of type com.kota.cc.model.Upload
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/model/Kopija.java:[140,125] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getBrojStrana()
  location: variable upload of type com.kota.cc.model.Upload
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/model/Kategorija.java:[45,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getPath()
  location: variable o of type com.kota.cc.model.Kategorija
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/model/Kategorija.java:[45,46] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getPath()
  location: class com.kota.cc.model.Kategorija
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/UploadService.java:[40,29] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method isJavan()
  location: class com.kota.cc.model.Upload
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/UserService.java:[62,18] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getRole()
  location: variable k of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/UserService.java:[67,21] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getRole()
  location: variable user of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[39,43] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getAccount()
  location: variable korisnik of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[43,33] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setAccount(com.kota.cc.model.Account)
  location: variable korisnik of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[48,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setDatum(java.time.Instant)
  location: variable tr of type com.kota.cc.model.Transakcija
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[49,34] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getUkupnaCena()
  location: variable nalog of type com.kota.cc.model.Nalog
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[50,38] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getKorisnik()
  location: variable nalog of type com.kota.cc.model.Nalog
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[51,35] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getRadnja()
  location: variable nalog of type com.kota.cc.model.Nalog
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[52,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setNalog(com.kota.cc.model.Nalog)
  location: variable tr of type com.kota.cc.model.Transakcija
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[53,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setAccount(com.kota.cc.model.Account)
  location: variable tr of type com.kota.cc.model.Transakcija
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[54,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setVrstaTransakcije(com.kota.cc.model.enumerated.VrstaTransakcije)
  location: variable tr of type com.kota.cc.model.Transakcija
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[57,44] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getStanje()
  location: variable korisnik of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[57,64] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getUkupnaCena()
  location: variable nalog of type com.kota.cc.model.Nalog
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[58,43] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getBalance()
  location: variable account of type com.kota.cc.model.Account
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[58,63] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getUkupnaCena()
  location: variable nalog of type com.kota.cc.model.Nalog
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[62,47] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getRadnja()
  location: variable nalog of type com.kota.cc.model.Nalog
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[64,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setDatum(java.time.Instant)
  location: variable trKlijent of type com.kota.cc.model.Transakcija
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[65,41] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getUkupnaCena()
  location: variable nalog of type com.kota.cc.model.Nalog
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[66,45] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getKorisnik()
  location: variable nalog of type com.kota.cc.model.Nalog
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[67,42] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getRadnja()
  location: variable nalog of type com.kota.cc.model.Nalog
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[68,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setNalog(com.kota.cc.model.Nalog)
  location: variable trKlijent of type com.kota.cc.model.Transakcija
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[69,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setAccount(com.kota.cc.model.Account)
  location: variable trKlijent of type com.kota.cc.model.Transakcija
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[70,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setVrstaTransakcije(com.kota.cc.model.enumerated.VrstaTransakcije)
  location: variable trKlijent of type com.kota.cc.model.Transakcija
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[72,38] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getRadnja()
  location: variable nalog of type com.kota.cc.model.Nalog
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[73,40] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getStanje()
  location: variable radnja of type com.kota.cc.model.Radnja
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[73,60] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getUkupnaCena()
  location: variable nalog of type com.kota.cc.model.Nalog
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[74,57] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getBalance()
  location: variable klijentAccount of type com.kota.cc.model.Account
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[74,78] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getUkupnaCena()
  location: variable nalog of type com.kota.cc.model.Nalog
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[84,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setDatum(java.time.Instant)
  location: variable tr of type com.kota.cc.model.Transakcija
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[85,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setIznos(java.lang.Double)
  location: variable tr of type com.kota.cc.model.Transakcija
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[86,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setKornisnik(com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik)
  location: variable tr of type com.kota.cc.model.Transakcija
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[88,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setVrstaTransakcije(com.kota.cc.model.enumerated.VrstaTransakcije)
  location: variable tr of type com.kota.cc.model.Transakcija
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[90,41] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getAccount()
  location: variable korisnik of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[91,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setAccount(com.kota.cc.model.Account)
  location: variable tr of type com.kota.cc.model.Transakcija
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[92,39] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getBalance()
  location: variable racun of type com.kota.cc.model.Account
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[95,44] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getStanje()
  location: variable korisnik of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[107,39] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getAccount()
  location: variable u of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[109,34] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setAccount(com.kota.cc.model.Account)
  location: variable u of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/KlijentServices.java:[59,47] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getZaKopiranje()
  location: variable nalog of type com.kota.cc.model.Nalog
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/KlijentServices.java:[68,40] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getTipProizvoda()
  location: variable p of type com.kota.cc.model.Radnja
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/KlijentServices.java:[70,65] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getCenovnik()
  location: variable r of type com.kota.cc.model.Radnja
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/KlijentServices.java:[98,24] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setGlavniKorisnik(com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik)
  location: variable klijent of type com.kota.cc.model.Klijent
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/KlijentServices.java:[99,27] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getFirma()
  location: variable klijent of type com.kota.cc.model.Klijent
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/KlijentServices.java:[101,38] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getFirma()
  location: variable klijent of type com.kota.cc.model.Klijent
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/KlijentServices.java:[102,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getMaticniBroj()
  location: variable firma of type com.kota.cc.model.Firma
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/KlijentServices.java:[102,59] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getMaticniBroj()
  location: variable firma of type com.kota.cc.model.Firma
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/KlijentServices.java:[104,71] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getMaticniBroj()
  location: variable firma of type com.kota.cc.model.Firma
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/KlijentServices.java:[106,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setFirma(com.kota.cc.model.Firma)
  location: variable klijent of type com.kota.cc.model.Klijent
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/KlijentServices.java:[108,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setFirma(com.kota.cc.model.Firma)
  location: variable klijent of type com.kota.cc.model.Klijent
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/KlijentServices.java:[109,24] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getRadnje()
  location: variable klijent of type com.kota.cc.model.Klijent
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/KlijentServices.java:[112,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setKlijent(com.kota.cc.model.Klijent)
  location: variable korisnik of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/KlijentServices.java:[115,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setRola(java.lang.String)
  location: variable ro of type com.kota.cc.model.Role
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/KlijentServices.java:[116,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getRole()
  location: variable korisnik of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/KlijentServices.java:[129,23] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setCenovnik(com.kota.cc.model.interni.Cenovnik)
  location: variable radnja of type com.kota.cc.model.Radnja
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/KlijentServices.java:[154,97] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getAdresa()
  location: variable nalog of type com.kota.cc.model.Nalog
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/AdresaServices.java:[65,47] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getAdreseIsporuke()
  location: variable korisnik of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/AdresaServices.java:[76,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setZip(java.lang.String)
  location: variable g of type com.kota.cc.model.Grad
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/AdresaServices.java:[81,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setGrad(java.lang.String)
  location: variable g of type com.kota.cc.model.Grad
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/AdresaServices.java:[100,29] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getAdresa()
  location: variable nalog of type com.kota.cc.model.Nalog
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/AdresaServices.java:[105,23] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setLokacija(com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point)
  location: variable adresa of type com.kota.cc.model.Adresa
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/AdresaServices.java:[116,31] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setFormatiranaAdresa(java.lang.String)
  location: variable adresa of type com.kota.cc.model.Adresa
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/AdresaServices.java:[117,31] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setLokacija(com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point)
  location: variable adresa of type com.kota.cc.model.Adresa
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/AdresaServices.java:[121,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable log
  location: class com.kota.cc.services.AdresaServices
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/AdresaServices.java:[128,45] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getLokacija()
  location: variable adresa of type com.kota.cc.model.Adresa
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/AdresaServices.java:[129,38] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getLokacija()
  location: variable adresa of type com.kota.cc.model.Adresa
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/AdresaServices.java:[131,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getLokacija()
  location: variable a of type com.kota.cc.model.Adresa
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/view/converters/AdresaConverter.java:[36,62] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getId()
  location: class com.kota.cc.model.Adresa
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/datamodel/MoreLikeThisLazyLoadDataList.java:[35,27] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getId()
  location: class com.kota.cc.model.Upload
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/datamodel/MoreLikeThisLazyLoadDataList.java:[49,30] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getId()
  location: variable object of type com.kota.cc.model.Upload
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/FullTextUploadService.java:[51,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable log
  location: class com.kota.cc.services.FullTextUploadService
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/managedbeans/ResetPasswordBean.java:[33,29] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getBrojTelefona()
  location: variable k of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/managedbeans/ResetPasswordBean.java:[33,60] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getBrojTelefona()
  location: variable k of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/managedbeans/ResetPasswordBean.java:[42,119] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getBrojTelefona()
  location: variable k of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/managedbeans/ResetPasswordBean.java:[67,33] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getConfirmationCode()
  location: variable k of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/logics/users/UserController.java:[83,28] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getBrojTelefona()
  location: variable korisnik of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/logics/users/UserController.java:[83,67] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getBrojTelefona()
  location: variable korisnik of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/logics/users/UserController.java:[84,48] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getBrojTelefona()
  location: variable korisnik of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/logics/users/UserController.java:[85,33] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setBrojTelefona(java.lang.String)
  location: variable korisnik of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
 /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[90,41] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getAccount()
[ERROR]   location: variable korisnik of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[91,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method setAccount(com.kota.cc.model.Account)
[ERROR]   location: variable tr of type com.kota.cc.model.Transakcija
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[92,39] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getBalance()
[ERROR]   location: variable racun of type com.kota.cc.model.Account
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[95,44] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getStanje()
[ERROR]   location: variable korisnik of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/services/TransactionService.java:[107,39] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getAccount()
[ERROR]   location: variable u of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] /C:/Users/kotar/git/CopyCenter/CopyCenter/src/main/java/com/kota/cc/logics/users/UserController.java:[101,33] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method setAccountNonLocked(boolean)
[ERROR]   location: variable korisnik of type com.kota.cc.model.Korisnik
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Reported missing methods should be generated by Lombok.

My pom.xml is

```
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            
             <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-layout</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <descriptors>
                                        <descriptor>src/assemble/layout.xml</descriptor>
                                    </descriptors>
                                    <finalName>${project.name}-layout-${project.version}</finalName>
                                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-theme</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <descriptors>
                                        <descriptor>src/assemble/theme.xml</descriptor>
                                    </descriptors>
                                    <finalName>${project.name}-theme-${project.version}</finalName>
                                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-sourcepath</arg>
                    <arg>${project.basedir}/src/main/java${path.separator}${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/annotations${path.separator}/</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Project is compiled by openjdk11.
It used to compile fine until I deployed it on a new Ubuntu server, when this error showed up.
And as I mentioned, after clearing local maven repository, same error arrised on my local computer from Eclipse. But running it from Eclipse as Spring project works fine.

Comment: You don't need to specify annotation processor path manually in the compiler plugin (**unless** you have more than one processor). Lombok will register itself

Comment: I tried without speciffying it but no result.